# Image search Python always run

Tags: python, image-processing

I am new to python

I have a simple question I wanna know how can i make a script that always look for a particular image,

for eg: I am playing mario then a green ledge came and the python codes check it instantly and print it, and when next ledge comes it scans the image and print it,

its just and example

The code below only works when i run the script and it will work once and then after that it wont,

I dont know about threading if someone can help me with a different approach i will be helpful

```
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import imagesearch

pos = imagesearch("./hi.png")
if pos[0] != -1:
    print("position : ", pos[0], pos[1])
else:
    print("image not found")
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't know that much, but you can build an image search engine with Python and OpenCV. Will you please refer to this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/)

Comment: i know that thats what i used

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this script in background then you can run this script using command prompt like "pythonw your_script.py", write pythonw not python. Put it in the while loop and pause a loop for 1 sec. Let me show you.

```
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import imagesearch
from time import sleep

while 1:
    pos = imagesearch("./hi.png")
    if pos[0] != -1:
        print("position : ", pos[0], pos[1])
        break
    else:
        print("image not found")

    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I didn't' paid attention to it. Thanks for correction.